# seamless circular coordinates

Tags: materials, shaders, shader-nodes, texture-coordinates, vector-mapping

I want a coordinate system that is kind of radial/circular and it should have **no visible border, mirroring or repetition of any kind**. I did my best to search, but only found a few things about polar coordinates. This was of course not helpful.
I have tried previously, and these are the only two that I was able to create.

[image]

In this, as one can see, the problem is the clearly visible border.

[image]

This one does not have any, border but the issue is that it's mirrored.

Is there a way to avoid any of these  issues?

(I know about mixing a gradient texture with the coordinates, but that does not give accurate circular coordinates)

Comment: A Polar coordinate system will allways break at 2Pi...But that is not really an issue, as long as the texture/shader that will be mapped in to these coordinates is seamless near both ends.

Comment: @Secrop I am trying to apply a procedural texture. Now since those are not seamless is there any way to avoid the borders or is what I am trying to achieve just impossible?

Comment: The procedural texture must tile at 2Pi [or in 0, 1], and then the seam will be gone. If not then you are bit out of luck.. You could try to turn the coordinates into a spiral, and then blend the upper cut with the lower cut.

Comment: Can you give an idea of the problem you're aiming to solve this way?

Comment: @RobinBetts There are actually about 15-20 effects I want to create. I abondened most of the projects. One example would be the iris. Most youtube videos use an image texture or a few of them have set the type to normal in the mapping node. These tricks don't work the way I want them to. They aren't customizable enough. I am probably going to delete this question as the more that I think about it the impossible it seems to get rid of the seam or the borders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pop into 3D, you can pick up  coordinates which are seamless there, and map those to a flat circle, one way or another:

[image]

Here, the wall of an (imaginary) capless cylinder is tapered to a cone, and then flattened to a circle. The mapped texture can be varied from radial to circular by adjusting the height of the cylinder ( the Length -> Z multiplier).

It might be the basis of various seamless circular effects, for your purposes.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much